# What to do, git, another variation of the application

Tags: git, github, merge

For example I have an application programmed in php, and by some time I created the same application using java, what do I do?

Should I create a new repository for it, or should I create a branch named `appname-java`, what would make sense?

After reading some branching tutorials, found this one "[Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)", I've learned that branching is for the 'another story' and will soon be merged to the master branch? Can someone explain further, and if I am correct, should I just branch instead of creating another repository, are there articles / related experiences supporting my idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create a new repository for it, or should I create a branch named appname-java, what would make sense?

Up to you, you're the one who decides. It's perfectly fine to have multi language implementation in one repository so you can update all in a single commit, but it's no problem to have separate repository for whatever other reason (say, some other time the java version will contain feature that will never exist in the php version).

> I've learned that branching is for the 'another story' and will soon be merged to the master branch?

Not always, but this is the most common scenario. Master branch contains the 'stable' version, while you might want to have several branches for stable + bugfixes, development (stable bug fixes, new features, new bugs) or anything else that can either later be merged to master or terminated (perhaps you finally realize that something is not possible to implement).